# Checking elements in a value in C

Tags: c

How do I read element by elements in C?

In Java I just do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
   if (str.charAt(i) == "X")
   return 1;
}
```

But I do I do something similar in C?

******Edit: I'm checking an int value for the first occurrence of 1, so the str operation doesn't work. Sorry i forgot to mention that at first.

Comment: In C, strings are char arrays, so you can iterate over string elements just as you do to any vector.

Comment: an integer value is binary encoded, so you will not be able to use the string functions.  You could use the sprintf function to convert the integer to a string, then use the string functions on the resulting  string

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare strings, and `strlen` to get their length.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you must know the length of the array: there is no language level ".length" to tell you.

However, Strings are null-terminated, so standard functions like strlen() can be used.

EXAMPLE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 10

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])

  int my_array[MAX_ELEMENTS];
  char my_string = "abc";
  int i;

  for (int i=0; i < MAX_ELEMENTS; i++)
    my_array[i] = i*2;
  for (int i=0; i < MAX_ELEMENTS); i++)
    printf ("my_array[%d]=%d\n", i, my_array[i]);


  for (int i=0; i < strlen(my_string); i++)
    printf ("my_string[%d]=%c\n", i, my_string[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the element directly:

```
int SIZE_OF_STRING = 5;
char string[SIZE_OF_STRING+1]; 

string[0] = 'h';
string[1] = 'e';
string[2] = 'l';
string[3] = 'l';
string[4] = 'o';
string[5] = '\0';

int sizeOfstring = strlen(string);

for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfstring; i++){
  if( str[i] == 'X'){
    return 1;
  }
}
```

You can also explicitly use `strcmp` if you want to compare 2 char arrays.

Comment: No!  Should be `char string[SIZE_OF_STRING+1];`, and you need `string[5] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
    if (str[i] == 'X')
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java strings hold at their beginning a 4 byte int value that indicates its size. Method `length()` just reads that value. In C however, string literals are ended with a null termination character `\0`. So `strlen()` in C iterates through single chars in string literal until it meets a `\0`. That's how it gets string's length.

If you would like to use a method on string which returns you string's length, you can go with C++ and use a `std::string` class. It has a `size()` method for example.

Here's a C code for snippet you provide.

```
#include<string.h>
/* ... */
size_t len = strlen(str);
for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++){
   if (str[i] == 'X')
       return 1;
}
```